# home made wine stuck at 6.5%

Tags: primary-fermentation

Does anyone know how to re-start a stuck wine made from top quality strawberry jam. I've already added re-start yeast but no joy. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is mentioned here recently. Don't use jam for wine. Just buy some frozen fruit and sugar. There are chemicals in jam that could inhibit fermentation. Plus you need extra nutrients.

Comment: What recipe did you use?

Answer (score 2):

Jam contains a chemical that interferes with the anaerobic respiration process of yeast. Next time, try avoiding using jam and switch to fruit concentrates without any preservatives. However, try adding some fermentable sugars to your batch to increase the alcohol content if the yeast is still active.

Answer (score 1):

Stuck fermentation is normally caused by lack of nutrient availability at the beginning of fermentation or lack of oxygen, according to Charlie Papazians Complete Joy of Homebrewing. He suggests getting yeast hulls and pitching 1/4-1/2 oz for 5 gallons along with additional yeast to get things going again. If you do decide to follow through on this suggestion let me know how it goes.

Tony